# scala bash applet not found when compiling

Tags: scala, windows-7-x64, scala-2.11

I downloaded scala from here: http://www.scala-lang.org/download/   and added *C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin* to the *Path* variable.
I am working with the scala plugin for eclipse, I install new software, as the video here says: http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html
I am working in Windows 7 64bit.

I am trying to run a simple object that is called HelloWorld, according to this tutorial: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaTutorial.pdf . my object has only the following code:

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
         println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

When I commit *scalac HelloWorld.scala*, in my *mobaxterm* it prints **bash: applet not found**.

I only saw a similar problem with *gradle* ([bash: applet not found when running gradle in MobaXterm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223994/bash-applet-not-found-when-running-gradle-in-mobaxterm)), but the solution seems irrelevant,as *gradle* has totally different files in it's installation directory.

---

EDIT:
I misunderstood the solution in the attached link, as I thought that *env.exe* and *busybox.exe* are files of *gradle*, but still, before making irreversible changes, I want to ask:
what should I do if cannot find the file *env.exe* in my file system, only *env*, which it's file type is "System File" and it is in *AppData/Local/Temp...* and *busybox.exe* exists only in *AppData/Local/Temp...* (or in folders that I don't have permission to access to).  I think it's not the solution that is offered in the attached link (since these are temporary files), but maybe I am wrong.

---

Thanks

Comment: Did you try what is suggested in that similar problem - "Long story short: To fix this issue, make /bin/env.exe a hardlink to /bin/busybox.exe or simply copy /bin/busybox.exe and rename it to env.exe in the Windows Explorer to get gradle finally running in MobaXTerm!"

Comment: @bjfletcher I edited the post, as I didn't understand that _env.exe_ and _busybox.exe_ are _MobaXterm_'s files, I thought they are _gradles_'s. But still I have a question, as mentioned in the EDITed section in the post. If you could clarify this, I will be grateful.  Thanks